# Why are quarters on the Enterprise-D so spacious?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, uss-enterprise

Watching TNG I noticed that nearly every crew member has very spacious quarters, which is something that does not seem practical on a space vessel.

Today's aircraft carriers house 3 officers to a room and 8 or more enlisted men to a room.

**Why are quarters on the Enterprise-D so spacious and is there evidence that lesser crew members had more confined/shared living quarters?**

Comment: specifically in next generation, the enterprise has many civilians as well as full families on board. the ship is meant to be almost a permanent residence. and since the saucer is meant to be detached the saucer portion is essentially a cruise ship, attached to a military vessel.

Comment: Todays crewmembers of naval vessels can at least leave their quarters now and then and have a look at the sea and the sky. On a space ship you've got essentially nothing but empty space. Given the long mission durations it's psychologically more than prudent to make the crew comfortable and the interior of the ship inviting. Living quarters as well as the renown holodeck accomplish that.

Comment: I don't think the constraints of naval ships apply. There are constraints on naval ship size besides structural strength and cost of material: Ships must observe hydrodynamic principles and withstand gravity. The Enterprise does not sail through matter, nor is it required to have full maneuver range in a gravity well.

Comment: See also: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/52541/why-star-trek-vessels-are-so-big-when-their-crew-is-so-small

Comment: I think it is not unreasonable to assume that federation citizens are used to a pretty high standard of living. also, they do not work for the money, they are basically all volunteers. providing nice living condition would be an incenitive to get crews. (or rather, bad conditions would deter people)

Comment: @superbest True that air or water resistance would presumably not be an issue for a spaceship. But making the ship bigger would still require using more materials, thus increasing mass. Assuming that the normal laws of physics apply, accelerating twice as much mass takes twice as much force and would thus consume twice as much fuel, even if that fuel is antimatter. (I suppose the normal laws of physics might NOT apply. How, exactly, does a warp drive work?)

Comment: @Jay - You press a button and it goes wooosh!

Comment: Cameras, lighting, and sound equipment mostly I would presume.

Comment: IIRC in the TNG episode where Scottie shows up he points out that the quarters on the D Enterprise are much larger than those on the original.

Comment: @EricLippert That's correct, he makes that observation.  It can be safely assumed that as the ship designs adapted for longer term missions that comfort became paramount.  To that end, a comparison in the same era could be that  the Enterprise D, a deep space exploration vessel, would have more comfort-inspired quarters than, say, the Defiant, a purpose-built mid range military escort vessel, which would not be on long term exploration missions and only short missions in which an individual may only spend a couple days in quarters at most.

Comment: @Jay The warp engines create a subspace warp field around the ship.  Effectively, I believe, this can lower its effective mass, allowing FTL acceleration (source for this speculation: Geordie extending the Enterprise warp field around an asteroid to lower its gravitational constant to exert more effect of the Enterprise tractor beam on a moon to push it back to orbit; also the subspace field formed around DS9 by O'Brien to move DS9 to the mouth of the wormhole by reducing effective mass of the station for transit mode with the control thrusters)

Comment: “which is something that does not seem practical on a space vessel” — the thing about space is that there’s quite a lot of space in space.

Comment: It's also the future. Our current navy vessels are crammed up because we suck. In the future we don't suck. Also, considering space has a tendency to generate uncomfortable feelings of isolation and claustrophobia, having a slightly larger living area might help keep the occupants feeling more comfortable.

Comment: Why so spacious? Well, it is a _space_-ship after all ;)

Comment: Because the Federation is weak and designed the ship for comfort instead of efficiency.

Comment: This is what comes of a millennia of generational entitlement.  Sure, today the kids all expect mobile phones and tablets.  By then, they want to take luxury craft into space.  Damned millennials...

Answer (score 82, accepted):

**Why the quarters are so spacious;**

- Ship space isn't at much of a premium. The ship can readily hold ten times the present crew when the need arises (for evacuation missions and emergencies) which means that for most of the time, the ship is 90% empty.
- The Enterprise is not a military vessel. Their primary mission is one of peaceful exploration. In addition to there being a considerable number of civilians on board, the crew are not expected to maintain military discipline in their quarters. Providing them with spacious accommodation would obviously lead to less stress and a happier and more productive crew.

The [TNG Technical Manual](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Star-Trek-Generation-Technical-Manual/dp/1852833408) has this to say on the subject;

> **Starfleet believes that providing comfortable living quarters to all
>   crew and attached personnel to be of primary importance.** Indeed,
>   living accommodations are one of the most visible displays of
>   Starfleet's commitment to caring for its single most important
>   "system," its people.
>
> ...
>
> **The living areas of the starship have been designed for maximum
>   comfort and safety while the crew is conducting a mission. Long-term
>   studies of humanoid cultures have confirmed that as each race embarked
>   upon permanent occupation of space, large personal living spaces had
>   to be established,** especially on early sublight expeditions. The
>   Enterprise allows for some 110 square meters of living space per
>   person, in addition to community space and the areas allocated to
>   purely working functions.
>
> While some engineers on the Galaxy Class Project questioned the
>   relatively large size of the vessel, opting for a smaller, more
>   efficient design, it was conceded that the large size provided a
>   greater number of mission options, given the changing social,
>   political, and economic conditions in the Milky Way.

---

**Do lesser crew members have less space?**

Yes, crew quarters aboard the Enterprise-D (at least for Starfleet personnel) are assigned and sized according to rank. In the episode [TNG : Lower Decks](http://leethomson.myzen.co.uk/Star_Trek/2_The_Next_Generation/Star_Trek_-_The_Next_Generation_Season_7/Star_Trek_-_The_Next_Generation_267_-_Lower_Decks.txt), we learn that junior officers (and probably enlisted crewpersons) are required to share quarters until they reach the rank of Lieutenant.

> **LAVELLE :** *Promote me, please -- **so I can make Lieutenant and have my own room**.*
>
> **TAURIK :** *If you aren't happy sharing quarters with me, then you should put in for a new room assignment. Just in case you're not
>   promoted.*

Above the junior ranks, Senior officers are provided with staterooms and at least one extra room for work/study. Picard and Riker use this extra space as separated visiting areas, Data uses his extra room as a private workspace and  Troi uses hers as an informal workroom with her famously messy desk. The ship also contains "apartments" for officers who choose to bring their families on board, comprised of two normal sets of quarters combined into a single living area.

[image: Picard's quarters]

Comment: Out of universe, it's a hell of a lot easier to film in a larger space. You have far more choices regarding angles and lighting.

Comment: Years ago I read an article by someone involved in producing the original series, and he commented that he would think that in real life, corridors on a space ship would be very narrow. The real reason why the corridors on the Enterprise were so wide, he said, was to make room for the cameras and lights.

Comment: 110 m^2 of living space is about 3 times more space than my family and I have now. Of course, I have easy access to much more community space (i.e. my entire community) than I would on a starship. On the other hand, I don't have any access to a holodeck so I still have to travel to experience new lands.

Comment: @johnny - I think the irony is that you have more variety of community space but far less ready access. The Enterprise strikes me as being much more like a cruise liner than an aircraft carrier.

Comment: @Richard - good point, if I want to go to a small park or soccer field, that's a 5 minute walk from home, if I want to go to a restaurant or gym, that's more like a 45 minute walk (or a 15 minute drive). So I have access to a wide variety of community space, but it's not always easy to get there.

Comment: @Johnny, if I remember correctly, the Enterprise has fewer than 5 holodecks for a crew that numbers in the hundereds, so it seems as if the only reason we see the holodeck being used so much by the same people is that the senior officers are the primary users of the holodeck.

Comment: 500 people sharing 5 holodecks means 100 per holodeck, or 3 days of use per year if shared equally. Even if they are only available 12 hours/day, that means 36 hours per person (longer if multiple people pool their time). That's still a lot of recreational time.

Comment: @johnny - There are 5 main holodecks  (for group or single use) as well as 22 smaller holosuites. As far as I can tell, they're open 24/7.

Comment: How does 110 m^2 per person and room sharing fit together?

Comment: @CodesInChaos - You basically get crapped on if you're a junior officer.

Comment: The quarters shown in the picture definitely don't look like 110 m² to me.

Comment: @Nathan - You're looking at Picard's quarters.

Comment: Umm, sorry to rain on the parade, but the Enterprise _is_ a military vessel: It's a ship of the UFP's military (well, space-navy); it's captained by a military officer and the crew is made up of military personnel. Other than crew families, it has few (or no?) permanent civilian residents. As for the peaceful exploration - come on... [We come in peace - shoot to kill, men](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FCARADb9asE).

Comment: @einpoklum - Nope. Uh-huh. [Starfleet is not a military organisation](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/54154/is-starfleet-a-military-or-civilian-organization)

Comment: Richard: It's got a command structure, everyone has his/her ranks,and its ships and personnel are generally heavily armed. Symbolically, its personnel are uniformed and it's called a 'fleet'. So, yeah, it is a military organization, your link notwithstanding.

Comment: @einpoklum - It's a peacekeeping force. That it's organised along military lines doesn't make it military, any more than the Salvation Army.

Comment: @Richard: Yeah, just like the US sends 'peacekeeping' force. People on the business end of a Federation proton torpedo launcher know exactly what this kind of peace keeping means.

Comment: Kind of begs the question ... if only 10% of the ship is generally occupied, why do they force Ensigns and crewmen to share quarters? Would it really eat into the emergency accommodation allowance that much to treat them as kindly as they treat everyone else? This seems wildly inconsistent. I would guess then that this facet of Lower Decks was one of the early signs of Trek venturing away from Roddenberry's core vision.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - For precisely the same reason they refused to allow troops to use the Staterooms on the [QE2](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/home/moslive/article-2128733/Queen-went-war-Amazing-pictures-QE2-sailed-Falklands.html), because it's the rules. Also, I'd guess there's an operational benefit in having people of the same rank sharing rooms

Comment: Dunno.. you don't have to give Ensigns access to the posh cutlery. But you didn't need to cram them up two per room either by the sounds of things. To go out of your way to make space travel comfortable but then flip around and make ensigns live cheaply to encourage rank progression or whatever seems, again, like an inconsistent vision

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - Being a Starfleet Ensign seems really really high stress. I would imagine that sharing that experience with someone would help to prevent the inevitable burnout.

Comment: Heh okay I'll buy that. Just about........ (Speaking personally it would make things 10x worse :P)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - Ask it as a new question. I'd be interested to see if there's an in-canon reason.

Comment: Agreed. Was thinking of how to formulate it as I wrote my comment. Glad you agree it's worthwhile, so when I get a chance I might put something together.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit There's also the question of how unoccupied "unoccupied space" is. The shuttlecraft bays have quite a bit of empty floor space and high ceilings to allow for maneuvering. Does all that count as "unoccupied"? Is occupied space just the residential sections?

Comment: @miltonaut: Unoccupied space is space that is fit/designed for habitation but presently unused. Basically, it's empty quarters.

Comment: @einpoklum: "Federation proton torpedo"?!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Photon torpedo. I hate how you can't correct comments...

Comment: @einpoklum: It's to make you live with your shame forever! (In all seriousness, being able to edit comments after the five minute grace period would result in all manner of hell-like chaos)

Comment: @einpoklum *Most* organisations have a Command Structure and Ranks, even if they're labelled slightly differently: e.g. "Organization Structure" and "Pay Grade".  Look at a real-life scientific research *fleet*, and you'll see that it's structured with the Ship Crew, the Scientists and the Engineers, in a similar manner to Starfleet.  And, if doing science somewhere dangerous (such as well-known for ships being attacked by Pirates), then they would *also* be armed.  Still doesn't make them Military.

Comment: @Chronocidal: 1. Can your bus driver order you to attention and lock you in the cargo compartment for insubordination? 2. It's true that Capitalist relations of production retain a lot of the hierarchical structure of slavery-based and/or feudal societies. But it's still not nearly as bad as military authority and discipline.

Comment: @einpoklum A Bus Driver, no (especially since, even if part of your company, they are unlikely to be that far up the command chain): but your commanding officer in the non-military ([by Treaty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antarctic_Treaty_System#Article_I)) [USAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Antarctic_Program), [AARI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arctic_and_Antarctic_Research_Institute), or [BAS](https://stackoverflow.com/) *could* - all of which are **much**  better matches for Starfleet than a bus company is.

Comment: @Chronocidal: 1. But Picard, who is the Enterprise''s bus driver, can do that to people on the space-bus-cum-warship. 2. I'm not from the US, so I don't know any of these, but if that's true, then those are examples of semi-militarized institutions.

Comment: @einpoklum only the USAP is American: AARI is Russian, and BAS is British (and, the "Bus Driver" would be Acting Ensign Crusher...).  However, you need to take into account that Picard, as captain of the ship, may be entitled to act as magistrate.  You're not about to claim that all Judges are Military now, are you? Or the Police Force?

Comment: Magistrate, in charge of diplomacy where he is in space, in charge of fighting wars, can order everyone around up to the most minute of details including clothing discipline, and his superiors (admirals) also make federation policy.

Answer (score 19):

The typical U.S. Navy deployment for a submarine or a surface ship is 3-6 months. In Star Fleet, the exploration missions last for years. NX-01 ultimately completed a 10 year mission of exploration. The NCC-1701 Enterprise originally had a 5 year mission. That is a long time to be in a ship.

From [Memory-Alpha](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Quarters)

> Crew's quarters: The majority of the enlisted crew and junior officers share quarters and bunk areas on small- to medium-sized vessels. (VOY: "Flashback") On starships of the Constitution-class, crew's quarters were structured as double suites, with private sleeping areas sharing a common, central bathroom. On starships of the Galaxy-class, crewmembers ranked Lieutenant junior grade or higher are given their own quarters while personnel up to the rank of ensign are required to share quarters. (TNG: "Lower Decks")
>
> Officers' quarters: Many starships feature separate quarters for higher-ranked officers. Usually, these staterooms are composed of two or more areas, featuring separate bed- and bathrooms and a dedicated work- and living area. (TNG: "Schisms")

Since the show focuses on the officers, with the only NCO of note bring Chief O'Brien (who has a family) we don't see much of the lower ranked officers or NCO quarters for regular crewmen. Here is an image of a room with double bunks and a common area.

[image]

As ships become larger, so do the accomodations. Here is a similar bunk bed situation on the NX-01

[image]

Comment: You've answered the what, but not the why.

Comment: Also, a bit too focused on Trek:Enterprise.

Comment: Do we ever see (Ensign) Wesley Crusher's accomodations, or does he live with his mother the entire time?

Comment: @Joe He does live with his mother.

Comment: Also, in the US Navy you get paid. Maybe should compare with a voluntary naval organisation (the RNLI? Greenpeace ships or Sea Shepherd?) instead.

Answer (score 15):

Modern warships have crew quarters that are extremely spacious compared to 18th century warships (which gave each man a space 14" wide in which to hang his hammock). *Star Trek* is merely extrapolating that trend into the future.

Comment: Plus, the Enterprise is not a warship to begin with. What's the cabin size on the USS Defiant?

Answer (score 12):

Somewhere, maybe even "Making of Star Trek" back in the 60s, Star Trek creator Gene Roddenberry was quoted as wishing to treat members of his space crew with a little more respect than one gets in the real-world navy. For the pilot episodes, the captains' quarters were designed per the producers' wishes; Kirk's was nice size, Picard's even bigger. For money reasons, those same rooms were reused when filming anyone else's quarters.

If you look at the deck plans sold for the 1701 ($5 in the 1970s!) and the 1701-D, they resemble cruise ships inside, with crew quarters stashed everywhere. In the 1701 plans, most rooms had 2 beds (I think).

Comment: "Picard's even bigger. For money reasons, those same rooms were reused when filming anyone else's quarters. " - While that is true for TOS, in TNG, there are at least two sets of quarters; senior officers (Riker, Dr. Crusher, Troi), as well as occasional high-ranking guests, use the same set as Picard's quarters, while for everyone else, the somewhat smaller junior officers' quarters sets were used, sometimes subdivided or extended with removable walls.

Answer (score 10):

It might sound trite, but I believe the main reason is *because they can*. The technology of the Federation allows starships with comfortable quarters. Sure, they could have extra phasers or cargo holds in that volume, but could they power those phasers? Do they need that cargo?

Comment: There are actual in-canon and logical reasons for the massive quarters, as mentioned in the other answers.

Comment: @Tritium21: ... and this is one of them. As mentioned in this answer. :)

Answer (score 7):

So many great answers. Wanted to throw in a few. Clearly, the out-of-world explanation helps explain the reality of the situation - big sets, easier to shoot (the TNG series was filmed on some fairly large studio equipment from the 1980s, cameras with wheels and tracks and such), and generally looks more glamorous, so it fits the theme of a Utopian-like future (for humanity, at least).

In-universe the long-duration missions are used to explain all "luxury-like" accommodations included (schools, arboretum, holodecks). It is established in "Lower Decks" that not everyone enjoys large quarters but our primary characters all have a good amount of space (similar to all the Trek series, excepting maybe Enterprise).

Technologically, it also makes more sense than it would on a modern day aircraft carrier. First, modern day aircraft carriers (from the US Fleet) have a personnel complement much higher. The recently deactivated USS Enterprise CVN65, for example, housed up to 4,600. TNG's Enterprise only houses ~1000 (including civilian families) with much larger emergency capacity.

Further, the Navy has to worry about gravity, whereas the Enterprise-D has to worry about structure. The larger those naval quarters, the more deck space, the more weight, the more furniture, etc. (just think how much space replicator functionality would save, food has to be stored somewhere). All of that mass adds up, so it's not so much that space is at a premium as it is mass. They could make bigger aircraft carriers but then they'd be even bulkier and more difficult to move, maintain and protect.

The Enterprise-D, with it's technology, just needs to form a stable warp-bubble and voila the "weight" of the thing is irrelevant. So you can afford spacious accommodations, large cargo decks, large shuttle bays (even the ones we see on camera were many times larger than the most efficient bay could imagine; ENT's shuttle bays for example) because your concern is the structural integrity of the vessel, not the weight.

The same could be said of modern spacecraft, things are tight because it's expensive to rocket all that mass into orbit. However, designs have been discussed like "inflatable spacecraft" that would allow relatively spacious accommodations. Just a matter of maintaining the integrity of the space vessel.

So, in-universe it makes sense that they'd have spacious quarters to match the rest of the spacious nature of the vessel. (Fun question)

Comment: The more the Replicators are used the more energy that needs to be created, which means more fuel that needs to be stored.  I don't think there is going to be as much difference in storage as you think, maybe it would be easier to store and food could be stored longer (because it's energy and not actually food)

Comment: @Malachi Fuel storage is pretty compact, however. They are using fusion along with even more efficient future tech, after all. And a lot of the energy for the replicators is recycled. It's so close to 100% that on Voyager, even with low replicator rations, they still go ahead and replicate the cups and dishes and then recycle them into the replicator, rather than reuse them to save energy.

Comment: Good Point @trlkly.

Answer (score 4):

Galaxy Class is an Explorer, to say the least, also a century since Starfleets prior vessels quarter size grew with technical complexity. As an explorer type it's got enough space (Cargo) to store several years worth of resources (spare parts, food stuffs, fuel)
People just don't understand how big it is. You could have the ENTIRE 1000 person crew on a single deck. For comparisons sake a Galaxy class has 1000 crew aboard with room for families and children. Using Constitution style quarters you could fit everyone on Deck 8.
An aircraft carrier holds 5500 on board (albeit the enlisted crew is triple bunked), The Titanic has room for 2000 passengers and 800 crew.
[image]

We only see Officers quarters on board the Enterprise D, we seldom see Enlisted quarters on board. Blueprints depict various multi-bed quarter rooms and four room apartments (families)[image]

Comment: Could you highlight how many people are commonly found on the other scale items?

Answer (score 3):

There are some pretty good answers here giving design philosophy etc. but lets just do a little rough math on the problem.

The Enterprise D is nearly 50 times the size of the aircraft carrier USS Enterprise (4.5 million tonnes vs. 95,000 tonnes displacement) yet it has a crew of 1012 against the 4600 crew of the carrier. Now NG Enterprise D has families as well so lets double its crew and add a little more to get 2300 or half the crew of the carrier (remember many of the crew are single).
This means that if the Enterprise D gave up as much of its space percentage wise as the carrier Enterprise, then each crew member would get 50 X 2 = 100 times the room available.

So now the enlisted crew instead of getting to share 1 room with 8 gets 12.5 rooms all to themselves. 
Space on a ship the size of the Enterprise D simply would not be a issue; the ship architects can give spacious quarters quite easily without compromising other design needs of a starship.
Various supplements to Star Trek have shown that lower ranks do get smaller rooms then officers which is traditional in naval vessels.

Comment: This is assuming that the whole ship is given over to living space, or that entire sections of the ship aren't devoted to other activities.

Answer (score 0):

On the debate about replicators being space-saving – The energy matrix required to form dishes as well as the food itself can be just as easily de-materialized and is reclaimed as 'free' energy back into the EPS system. They function on technology similar to that of transporters, but with lower resolution. Another thing to consider is waste processing and reclamation. All biological wastes are fed into a processing location where, basically, those materials are vaporized into the same kind of energy and fed into the system. If you think about it in a strictly linear sense, it's kind of 'gross'. However, it's very efficient, which means that there is less deuterium and anti-deuterium consumed to create the energy needed for the process.

In the Trek verse, Matter/Anti-Matter Reactor Assemblies (MARAs) – a.k.a. the Warp Core – can produce tremendous amounts of energy from very little matter. This is in addition to what supplemental fusion reactors aboard ship also produce, which have also become remarkably efficient and compact. A Next Generation fusion reactor could fit into your bedroom without much extra needed. Oh, and they're much safer.

Another thing to consider is that, on the matter of structure, all TNG era and beyond Trek vessels and stations have 'structural integrity fields', which are basically reinforcing forcefields that snap on when needed to reinforce materials and points of stress. Concerns for size and mass are somewhat mitigated by the usage of these fields, especially during combat or other emergency situations. Federation ships are meant to be tough, and are designed for survivability. It was stated in another answer that a five- to ten-year mission out in the black, often with little to no support, is not uncommon.

These elements do play into the consideration when considering the size of quarters.

Comment: Reclaimed free energy? Vaporized into energy? Your second paragraph does indicate where a starship's very large energy budget comes from, but that energy is used to do work, and the first paragraph is full of unsupported claims.

Answer (score 0):

As many other have already stated, the Enterprise D was a cruise ship attached to a military vessel.  One of the key things to remember is that on the 178 episodes of The Next Generation we saw a VERY small percentage of the interior spaces of the ship.  The saucer module was where the vast majority of the living and recreational spaces were contained.  In the show, the saucer module was about 1000 feet across from port to starboard and 16 decks high from the bridge on deck one to the Captain's Yacht on deck 16.  We only saw a small sampling of crew quarters, some cargo bays, sickbay, the transporter room, a couple of lounges and ten-forward, sickbay, and the holodeck. There were complete blueprints drawn up for the entire ship that showed schools, restaurants, and five-deck high mall/promenade, aquatic research labs, a two-deck theater, and much more.  The budget constraints of the production limited what we saw on TV, but in-universe the ship was intended to be a city-in-space for over 1000 officers, civilians, and even children and spouses.  The USS Voyager was shown to be much smaller but also quite spacious relative to the number of people onboard.  The USS Defiant was much more akin to the accommodations of a modern naval vessel with shared accommodations for all crew and very tight interior spaces.  The galaxy-class Enterprise-D was not necessarily representative of life on every Starfleet vessel.

Comment: The saucer was not a cruise vessel and the Federation isn't a military.