# On Enterprise-D, what are the accommodations for lower ranking officers with families?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, uss-enterprise

Following up on [Why are quarters on the Enterprise-D so spacious?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/77529/why-are-quarters-on-the-enterprise-d-so-spacious),

What about officers below Lieutenant who have families?

Comment: Cargo bays. Or transporter buffers.

Comment: I was under the impression that officers below Lieutenant aren't allowed to have their families on board.

Comment: Cargo bays would be fine until they try to make their own booze!

Comment: @Richard unless you are Chief O'Brien

Comment: @JackBNimble - Ah, but he met his wife (an existing civilian consultant) **on board** the Enterprise. It's hardly fair to kick them off just because she got pregnant.

Comment: Of course O'Brien wasn't a commissioned officer. The quarters for NCOs may be again different from commissioned ones.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, "The Lower Decks" is one of the few times we see junior officer quarters of any kind, and have it confirmed that, at least on a *Galaxy* Class ship, they have to share quarters. To my knowledge, we never see a junior officer with a family, and so there cannot be a canonical answer to the question.

That said, I can think of two equally plausible alternatives:

- Instead of bunking with another junior officer/noncom, they room with their family, but in the same space.
- Junior/noncoms who aren't married to a more senior officer or a civilian consultant (e.g. Keiko) can't have their family aboard.

The former makes sense in the context of the originally intended "mission" for the *Enterprise*-D, which was long-range exploration with only rare contact with home. This conception of the *Enterprise* was almost-but-not-quite a generation ship and was one of the major reasons for families being included at all.

The latter makes more sense in the context of the way the series actually played out, where the *Enterprise*-D was in regular touch with Star Fleet and often put in to Federation worlds and bases, meaning that junior officers could visit their families on leave, and also eventually get promoted and bring their families on-board later.

Comment: We do see Ensign Daniel Sutter with his daughter Clara in the TNG episode "Imaginary Friend".  Their quarters seem to be as spacious as the senior officers.  Maybe it's as simple as, if you have family with you, you get family quarters.

Comment: I suspect honestly that was just a case of, "Well...we already have the set up..." :-D

Comment: It may have something to do with the ship's size. In [TNG Ep. 6x24 Second Chances](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Second_Chances_(episode)), Thomas Riker makes a reference to some time frame after which he could bring family aboard. Then again, there's some contradictory information about what class the [U.S.S. Ghandi](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/USS_Gandhi) was.